# I want to close the select menu after selecting something from list

Tags: javascript

```
 <div class="topbar__menu">
            <button
              class="
                topbar__button topbar__button--has-arrow topbar__menu-button
              "
              type="button" id="hideselectOption"
            >
              <span class="topbar__button-label">Language:</span>
              <span class="topbar__button-title" style="text-transform: uppercase !important;">{{lang}}</span>
              <span class="topbar__button-arrow"
                ><svg width="7px" height="5px">
                  <path
                    d="M0.280,0.282 C0.645,-0.084 1.238,-0.077 1.596,0.297 L3.504,2.310 L5.413,0.297 C5.770,-0.077 6.363,-0.084 6.728,0.282 C7.080,0.634 7.088,1.203 6.746,1.565 L3.504,5.007 L0.262,1.565 C-0.080,1.203 -0.072,0.634 0.280,0.282 Z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </span>
            </button>
            <div class="topbar__menu-body" >
              <span class="topbar__menu-item" ng-click="changeLanguage('en')">
                <img src="public/assets/images/languages/usa.png" alt="" />
                <span>English</span>
              </span>
              <span class="topbar__menu-item" ng-click="changeLanguage('vn')">
                <img src="public/assets/images/languages/veitnam.png" alt="" />
                <span>Vietnam</span>
              </span>
              <span class="topbar__menu-item" ng-click="changeLanguage('ar')">
                <img src="public/assets/images/languages/dubai.png" alt="" />
                <span>Arabic</span>
              </span>
              <span class="topbar__menu-item" ng-click="changeLanguage('th')">
                <img src="public/assets/images/languages/thailand.png" alt="" />
                <span>Thai</span>
              </span>
              <span class="topbar__menu-item" ng-click="changeLanguage('rus')">
                <img src="public/assets/images/languages/russia.png" alt="" />
                <span>Russian</span>
              </span>
            </div>
```

```
<script>
     
     $(function() {
        $('.indicator--trigger--click .indicator__button').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const dropdown = $(this).closest('.indicator');

            if (dropdown.is('.indicator--open')) {
                dropdown.removeClass('indicator--open');
            } else {
                dropdown.addClass('indicator--open');
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', function (event) {
            $('.indicator')
                .not($(event.target).closest('.indicator'))
                .removeClass('indicator--open');
        });
    });


    $(function() {
        $('.topbar__menu-button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).closest('.topbar__menu').toggleClass('topbar__menu--open');
        });

        $(document).on('click', function (event) {
            $('.topbar__menu')
                .not($(event.target).closest('.topbar__menu'))
                .removeClass('topbar__menu--open');
        });
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: The question only contains code. It would be nice if you could add some context. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add code below.

```
function changeLanguage () {
    /// change language code...
    document.querySelector(".topbar__menu-body").style.display = "none";
}
```